# Waiting for Specific element to appear (Appium, Java)

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, automation, appium

so for my automation program I need to time how long it takes for our ad to play. The way I go about doing this is having a variable called timeStart = System.NanoTime(); and another one called estimatedTime = System.NanoTime() - timeStart.

Now, my question however is how do I properly tell it to wait? When I run my code I do get a result, but it also prints out the result even if the the little textfield doesn't appear on the left side yet. I have looked through some of the solutions here, and that is how I got to what I have currently. But I am still not positive it fully does what I need.

Therefore, the concise question is: How do I tell my application constantly wait and search for a particular name of an object and/or xCode (assuming it doesn't take too long), without it throwing an ElementNotFound exception?

Below is my code:

```
public static void timerForAd(Logger logger, IOSDriver driver) throws InterruptedException
{

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    //String pathWay = "//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAWebView[1]/UIAStaticText[2]"; 

    long estimatedTime;

    try
    {
        synchronized(driver)
        { 

            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("Ad")));
        }

        estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        logger.info("Estimated Time for the the Ad to play is: " + estimatedTime);


    }catch(Exception E)
    {
        logger.info("Exception occured in timerForAd method, see if you can fix it.");
        E.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I made some slight modification. the code between the synchronized(driver) now looks like: startTime = System.nanoTime();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(pathWay)));

Comment: The synchronized driver was removed, it seems to work closer to how I suspect it should.